# Multiple contour plots in the same plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, contour

I am new to R and trying to draw multiple 2D contour plots in the same plot. I  tried with the following code.

```
dat1 <- structure(list(x1 = c(1:10), y1 = c(10:20)), .Names = c("x1", "y1"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-21L))
dat2 <- structure(list(x2 = c(10:20), y2 = c(20:30)), .Names = c("x2", "y2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-21L))
Contourcolors <- colorRampPalette(c('yellow',"red"))(20)
PointColors <- c(rep('green',5),rep('blue',5))
filled.contour(z=dat1,col=Contourcolors,
               plot.axes=points( x=seq(0, 1, length.out = nrow(dat1)),
                                 y=rep(.5,20), 
                                 col=PointColors,cex=5,pch=19)
)
Error in as.matrix.data.frame(x) : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
```

How can I do this easily with R?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, but `lattice` plots or `ggplot2` plots might be useful here.

Comment: your dat1 and dat2 have only x and y you need a z to be able to make filled.contour plot. It's well explained here https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/filled.contour.html

Comment: I agree, please check your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your data is making much sense here, but perhaps you are looking for something like this?

```
dat1 <- data.frame(x = c(0:10), y = c(10:20))
dat2 <- data.frame(x = c(10:20), y = c(20:30))

dat3 <- cbind(rbind(dat1, dat2), df = rep(c('1', '2'), each = 11))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat3, mapping = aes(x, y, col = df)) + 
  geom_density2d()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my original data, the length of vectors in dat1 and dat2 are different. In that  case, what I have to write instead of each=11?

Comment: Something like rep.int(c('1', '2'), c(nrow(dat1), now(dat2)))

Comment: If you mean that the length of `x` and `y` differ (like in the example data you gave) then I don't understand what the plot is supposed to show. A plot with an `x` and `y` axis needs paired data. You can exclude missing data.

Comment: for eg. the length of  x and y vectors in dat1 is 36. the length of x and y vectors in dat2 is 68. Hope you understand my problem. I tried your code. But I got the error like this  Error in rep.int(c("1", "2"), c(nrow(dat1), now(dat2))) :   could not find function "now"

Comment: sorry typed that on my phone, should be `rep.int(c("1", "2"), c(nrow(dat1), nrow(dat2)))` (pretty obvious I think)